# How to hide a field in editable mode in odoo (version 8 to 15)

Tags: python, css, xml, odoo-8, odoo-14

In **odoo v8**, I want some fields to be shown only in view mode but when the user clicks on edit or create, then those fields should be invisible (**Only visible in view mode**).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is an openerp class called `oe_read_only`.

This will allow you to view the field only when reading the form not in edit mode of the form.

Sample Code:

```
<field name="name" class="oe_read_only"/>
```

Comment: this is very useful